# StepFunction, DynamoDB: Query condition missed key schema element

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-step-functions, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to query a DynamoDB table in a Step Function but it's throwing the following error.

```
Query condition missed key schema element: Scope (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: FN4G...)
```

The Step Function Task definition is;

```
    "Obtain Users info": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Parameters": {
        "TableName": "Users",
        "KeyConditionExpression": "#Scope = :Global",
        "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
          "#Scope": {
            "S": "Scope"
          }
        },
        "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
          ":Global": {
            "S": "Global"
          }
        }
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:dynamodb:query",
      "Next": "Pass"
    },
```

The DyanmoDB definition is;
[image]

And here's a sample item from the table

```
{
  "Scope": {
    "S": "Global"
  },
  "ServiceName": {
    "S": "driver"
  },
  "lastVisitDateTime": {
    "N": "1680022106"
  },
  "Status": {
    "S": "ONLINE"
  }
}
```

Any pointers on what I'm missing??  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters should be as follows:

```
    "Obtain Users info": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Parameters": {
        "TableName": "Users",
        "KeyConditionExpression": "#Scope = :Global",
        "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
          "#Scope": "Scope"
        },
        "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
          ":Global": {
            "S": "Global"
          }
        }
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:dynamodb:query",
      "Next": "Pass"
    },
```

ExpressionAttributeNames does not take a data type as they are always defined as strings.

Comment: Thank you!   I completely overlooked that.